# Up Hill vs. Down Hill

Tags: phrases, expressions, american-english, metaphors

The expression "It's all up hill from here!" and "It's all down hill from here!" mean that things will only get better or things will only get worst.

Metaphorically going uphill can provide for a better position, while going down hill is easier.

Which expression represents which way?

Comment: [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=uphill+from+here%2Cdownhill+from+here%2C+up+hill+from+here%2Cdown+hill+from+here&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuphill%20from%20here%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdownhill%20from%20here%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdown%20hill%20from%20here%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: My gut feeling is that "uphill from here" is a bastardization of "downhill from here" much like "I could care less" or "things will only get worst" ;).

Comment: I dunno answer, so I'll just leave it for a week, then green check mark whichever has the most upvoted

Comment: "The expression[s] ... mean that things will only get better or things will only get wors[e]" -- no, they don't mean that. They mean that everything will be easier (downhill) or harder (uphill) from here.  And you have confused "it's all downhill from here" with "everything is going downhill", the latter meaning that that the situation is getting very bad; "nosediving", like a stock chart with falling prices.

Comment: In Minnesota, in the winter, on ice, you often want to be going uphill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you face an uphill battle, you are marching against gravity. This would be more difficult.

Hence,

> [When I was your age](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhenIWasYourAge), I walked fifteen miles to school, through the snow, uphill, both ways!

(Warning: hyperlink goes to TV Tropes, where you will lose track of time.)